# This guy's alright in my book, because he used the word "rapscallion". Meaning

Tags: meaning

> **This guy's alright in my book**, because he used the word "rapscallion".
>
> [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378976/unexplained-clutter-in-a-post-edited-back-in-by-author/379059?noredirect=1#comment663338_379059)

What it means by alright in my book?

Answer (score 3):

"In my book" means "in my opinion", "according to my belief system". The commenter approves of the other person's vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

That means he likes the way that guy wrote because that same guy used a word he particularly enjoyed.